# SQL a number between a table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to ask about how to query a database to get a number between a table. What I know is get a table between a number.

My case is I have a number, example: 101, then it will match at database with this table:

```
tableNumber
StartNo(int) | FinishNo(int)
```

Now, how to get know that my number is between StartNo and FinishNo? I've google about this but only get BETWEEN, but between is only for table that range from number. The between syntax is like this : "where number Between(1,2)" what i want is something like "where 101 between (startno, finishno)"

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: I don't get what you're asking, between works in both cases (with the right syntax, which is `X between Y and Z`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`between` works. like this:

`select * from tableNumber where YOURNUMBER between startno and endno`

and here's a demo to show it in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/471bf/1

[from the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) the `between` syntax is simply `expr BETWEEN min AND max`. it doesn't care if `expr` or `min` or `max` are literals or fields or otherwise.

Comment: Why my query doesn't works then? I already try that.. even I've try at phpmyadmin

Comment: in order to do that you'd have to paste your query somewhere.

Comment: well, I know the problem... got a typo at my long query... I tried Your query and it works... sorry for my bad... should I delete this question?

Comment: you could, or you could accept the answer if it was helpful